# Minkowski Metric

Tags: special-relativity

Hi all I'm a little confused

So I have that in special relativity time is included as a coordinate  so that in 1 spatial dimension we have 2 space time coordinates. The most basic metric is the Minkowski metric given by $\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1}&0 \\ 
  0&1 
\end{array}} \right]$     so now if I have a vector $\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  1 \\ 
  1  
\end{array}} \right]$ and I use Einstein Summation Convention with the metric I get $-1 + 1 =0$      ... so what does this tell me about the length squared of the vector.. why is the $0$    significant ?

EDIT: I found out that if the length squared = $0$ the interval is then light-like and light-like particles have world-lines confined to the light cone and the square
of the separation of any two points on a light-like world line is zero. Is this correct ?

Help is very much appreciated

Thank you =)

Answer (score 3):

We assume that we are working in units where  the speed of light $c=1$.  Given a vector with time and space components $A=(A^t, A^x)$, the Minkowski square of the vector is
\begin{align}
  A^2 = -(A^t)^2+(A^x)^2
\end{align}
We can classify the vector $A$ according to the sign of its square length.  In particular, in the given signature (with the minus sign in the time coordinate) we use the term **timelike** to refer to any vector with $A^2<0$, **lightlike** to refer to any vector with $A^2=0$, and **spacelike** to refer to any vector with $A^2>0$.

Therefore, the vector you wrote down is said to be lightlike.

One way of attaching physical significance to these terms is by considering trajectories of particles moving in spacetime.  If a massive particle moves in spacetime, then the tangent vector to its trajectory will be timelike, while when a massless particle moves through spacetime, the tangent to its trajectory will be lightlike.  In order for the tangent vector to a trajectory to be spacelike, it would have to be moving faster than light.

So the vector you wrote down could be the tangent vector to the path of a massless particle moving through spacetime, like a photon.

Comment: Thank you, follows the information I found in special relativity =) Should be sufficient.. I'll go make sense of it.

Thank you once again